# DataIntegrityViolationException while storing entity

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm writing simple web application using Spring Boot and MySQL as database. Code is below

I have an entity User:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(UserKey.class)
public class User {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Item> items;
    private String fullName;
    @Id
    private String principalId;
    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private LoginProvider loginProvider;
}
```

I also have a UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public User getCurrentUser() {
        try {
            return (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addItemToUser(Item item) {
        User currentUser = getCurrentUser();
        if (!currentUser.getItems().contains(item)) {
            currentUser.getItems().add(item);
            userRepository.save(currentUser);
        }
    }
}
```

And a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
PostMapping(value = "/addItem/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    public void addItemToUser(Map<String, Object> model, @PathVariable int id) {
        userService.addItemToUser(itemService.getItem(id));
    }
}
```

It's my Item class:

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Enumerated
    private Category category;


    public Item() {
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Item item = (Item) o;

        return id == item.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

And it's my repository:

`public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {}`

Controller and everything are working just fine but sometimes the following error occurs when I,m trying to update a list with my users items:

```
    2018-04-03 17:09:53.814 ERROR 24265 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '23942983472937-FACEBOOK-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar:5.1.42]
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted your `Item` class. My guess would be that you need to implement `equals(Object obj)` & `hashCode()` methods so that your `Set<Item>` doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: I,ve updated my question. `hashCode` and `equals(Object object)` methods are already implemented. Maybe i did it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement `equals(Object obj)` and `hashCode()` this way:

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = (prime * result) + (int) id;
        result = (prime * result) + ((category == null) ? 0 : category.hashCode());

        return result;
    }

@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    final Item item = () obj;
    if (id != item.id)
        return false;
    if (!category.equals(item.category))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

into your all using classes `UserKey`, `User`, `Item`, `Category`, `LoginProvider`. And also try to add this annotations to your Item id:

```
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Before testing please remove all your records, to be sure that your primary key is unique.